# Cross Server Select In SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, sqlalchemy

Is it possible to make SQLAlchemy do cross server joins?

If I try to run something like

```
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://SERVER/Database')

query = sql.text('SELECT TOP 10 * FROM [dbo].[Table]')

with engine.begin() as connection:
    data = connection.execute(query).fetchall()
```

It works as I'd expect. If I change the query to select from `[OtherServer].[OtherDatabase].[dbo].[Table]` I get an error message `"Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\\ANONYMOUS LOGON"`

Comment: It's strange situation when you need to perform a query to a server within a connection to a different server. Why you can't just have two separate connections?

Comment: It is. The actual query is doing an `INSERT INTO`, as well as bunch of gymnastics like truncating the table first, and using `TABLOCKX`. Needs to be done with one connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mssql+pyodbc://SERVER/Database?trusted_connection=yes` threw an error when I tried to it. It did point me in the right direction though.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, sql
import urllib

string = "DRIVER={SQL SERVER};SERVER=server;DATABASE=db;TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES"
params = urllib.quote_plus(string)
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={0}'.format(params))


query = sql.text('SELECT TOP 10 * FROM [CrossServer].[datbase].[dbo].[Table]')

with engine.begin() as connection:
    data = connection.execute(query).fetchall()
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there's an issue with how you authenticate to SQL server.

I believe you can connect using the current Windows user, the URI syntax is then `mssql+pyodbc://SERVER/Database?trusted_connection=yes` (I have never tested this, but give it a try).

Another option is to create a SQL server login (ie. a username/password that is defined within SQL server, NOT a Windows user) and use the SQL server login when you connect.

The database URI then becomes: `mssql+pyodbc://username:password@SERVER/Database`.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite complicated if you suppose to alter different servers through one connection.
But if you need to perform a query to a different server under different credentials you should add linked server first with [`sp_addlinkedserver`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx). Then it should be added credentials to the linked server with [`sp_addlinkedsrvlogin`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189811.aspx). Have you tried this?

Comment: Yes. The servers are linked. I can run the query fine from within SQL Server.